# Answer 16 minutes after the question was closed?

Tags: discussion, support, bug

How is this possible?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you start an answer before the question is closed, you are still allowed to post it.

Comment: When did that functionality change take place? In the past, I had numerous cases where I started the answer, only to get notice that I can't post it because the question got closed in the meanwhile.